# how to list all subdomain in wordpress multiuser

Tags: multisite, buddypress, list

I need to show all sub domains/directory in my wordpress multiuser,
for eg:
       [blog1](http://blog1)
      [blog2](http://blog1)
      [blog3](http://blog1)

Is their any template tags to do this? stuck with this help me out guys.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this plugin :

[**`Multi-Site Site List Shortcode`**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multi-site-site-list-shortcode/)

or if you prefer a snippet then:

```
$blog_list = get_blog_list( 0, 'all' );
if (count($blog_list) > 1){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($blog_list AS $blog) {
        echo '<li>Blog '.$blog['blog_id'].': '.$blog['domain'].$blog['path'].'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>'
}
```

Comment: I know this is super old, but WP wants us to use `get_sites` now. Still, this does currently work as of v 5.9